# Xcode 9.2 Upload to App Store fails with description length and invalid toolchain errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I've read through a bunch of forums including here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87862
and some Stack Overflow posts.

I have tried modifying my plist using the proposed solution of

```
find Products/ -name Info.plist -print0 | xargs -0n1 plutil -replace BuildMachineOSBuild -string 16A323
```

in the archive directory that I'm trying to load, and I'm still receiving the error below. I believe I have valid Xcode and Mac OS versions. I'm running Xcode 9.2 which was released today and High Sierra 10.13.1. Why does my upload fail with these errors and how can I fix it?

[image: upload error messages]

The errors in text (to make this post more searchable):

> The following issues occurred while distributing your application.
>
> ⚠ **iTunes Store Operation Failed**
>    description length:2651858
>
> ⚠ **iTunes Store Operation Failed**
>    ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds."

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I have a feeling that iTunes Connect hasn't caught up to the fact that xCode 9.2 was released today. Perhaps by tomorrow it'll validate. In the past, I've seen reports of the 2 being out of sync for a short time.

Answer (score 19):

Right-Click on the archive file (.xcarchive) > Show Package Contents > Products > Applications > Right-Click on the app file > Show Package Contents > Double-Click on ***Info.plist*** to edit it

Change value of **DTXcodeBuild** from **9C40b** to **9C40**

Re-submit and it will work

Edit/Disclaimer: this is just a trick to bypass the upload process, iTunesConnect still doesn't allow submission with 11.2 so this is not the right solution.

Comment: If you're not good at following instructions like me - note you have to go further into the archive than just the plist at the root.

Comment: This solves only the upload process problem, your app gonna fail during processing in iTunes Connect!

Comment: You may as well remove ALL the build related entries from the plist. E.g, apps built with Xojo do not contain any such info and yet they are accepted by Apple. You may have to re-sign the app after your changes, though, not sure (by using the codesign command manually).

Comment: FYI this will get the build to upload but you won't be able to submit in iTunes Connect you'll get "Invalid sdk value. The value provided for the sdk portion of LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS in [app name] is 11.2 which is greater than the maximum allowed value of 11.1."

Comment: This will allow the upload to go through in Xcode but you'll still get an email from iTunes Store with the same message and the build won't be available.

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "[app name].

The following are for your information only and do not require any action:

Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds.

Regards,

The App Store team

Comment: Come on... why are you accepting an answer, if it really NOT A CORRECT answer, and why the upvotes? What are you thinking? Apple just do the validation from one String from a Plist ? :D Are you kidding me? This really NOT SOLVE this problem! This just mislead the readers...

Comment: Doesn't work for me. You cannot submit build with this solution.

Answer (score 5):

I started with several "iTunes store operation failures". While fixing the other errors, I keep trying to fix this "description length" error too - but it always failed.
So I solved all other errors first and suddenly this error was gone too.

I BELIEVE this error depends on other errors. The last error I fixed was called "Storyboard file not found")

Xcode 9.2

Comment: At first the answer looks luck but it actually worked!

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE:
Although my option may let you upload the package to iTunesConnect successfully, but may fail when you click Submit for Review.

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjeb9.jpg)

Right-Click on the archive file (.xcarchive) > Show Package Contents > Products > Applications > Right-Click on the app file > Show Package Contents > Double-Click on Info.plist to edit it

Change **DTXcodeBuild**'s value from **9C40b** to **9C40** and it will work.

Comment: This will allow the upload to go through in Xcode but you'll still get an email from iTunes Store with the same message and the build won't be available. Dear developer, We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "[app name]. The following are for your information only and do not require any action: Invalid Toolchain - New apps and app updates must be built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and iOS SDK. Don't submit apps built with beta software including beta macOS builds. Regards, The App Store team

Comment: Same for me. I was able to upload, but after tapping "Submit for Review" I received a list of errors.

Comment: @JustinVallely Yes, that's the final problem I've updated in my answer, and now iTunes Connect accepts the binary build with Xcode 9.2 (9C40b).

Comment: @TimurBernikowich now iTunes Connect accepts the binary build with Xcode 9.2 (9C40b), I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a discussion on this subject : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93253
They advise to wait for the deployment of the new Xcode version number on the backend or come back to Xcode 9.1, it seems it works.

UPDATE : Change the DTXcodeBuild doesn't work

Comment: by downgrading do you mean removing XCode and reinstall 9.1 image?

Answer (score 3):

**Hard Clean Product** worked for me.

Hard clean the product by **Command + Shift + Alt + K**, then upload a new build to AppStore.

I hope this will work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Already Fixed, just try again to submit the app.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was solved for me with installing the latest stable release of Xcode 9.2 (mac OSX Sierra 10.12.6)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround it:
Download Xocde 9.1 from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Make a fresh archive then upload it. It worked for me.

P.S. I did not send for review but I sent it to internal testers including myself.

Comment: Did you uninstall your previous 9.2 XCode or did an overwriting?

Comment: Or rename the app Xcode9.1 and put it in your Applications folder

Comment: @Sammy you can. You can copy the device model folders to XCode 9.1