# iTunes Store operation failed ERROR ITMS-90534 "invalid toolchain" on XCode 9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, xcode9.2

I got some issue while distributing my new build since the new **XCode 9.2** update.

Please help me to solve.

[image: Error]

Comment: Similar problem is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644270/xcode-9-2-upload-to-app-store-fails-with-description-length-and-invalid-toolchai

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the following link, if not, check once.

[Xcode 9.2 Upload to App Store fails with description length and invalid toolchain errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644270/xcode-9-2-upload-to-app-store-fails-with-description-length-and-invalid-toolchai?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And also this I got someone posted following reply other query.

I heard few people faced this too. Apple has just released the Xcode 9.2 update and might not have updated iTunes connect to accept builds from it yet. It might be resolved soon in a couple of hours or days.

So, check with Apple Team regarding this issue instead of waiting for submission till fix this issue by Apple.

Comment: Thank you so much, we got exacty the same issue

Comment: You are welcome :)