# ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid." description length:5318

Tags: ios, xcode

I have been an error at the time of submission of APP

This problem has lasted for half a month

> iTunes Store Operation Failed description length:5318
>
> iTunes Store Operation Failed
>   ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."

System environment

OS version :10.13.2

Xcode version:9.2

application Loader version:3.7

[image: Xcode upload error image]

[image: application Loader upload error image]

The following is the application loader error log

```
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Transporter is skipping bundle update check: Already checked recently.
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: MD5 checksum calculation in the transporter will be skipped.
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Logging level set to eXtreme
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Logging configured successfully.
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DEBUG: Attempting refresh of configuration data from https://contentdelivery.itunes.apple.com/transporter/Defaults.properties
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DEBUG: Configuration refresh successful.
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DEBUG: Saving configuration to local path: /Users/Darren/.itmstransporter/Defaults.properties
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: iTMSTransporter : iTunes Store Transporter [1.9.6]
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: OS identifier: Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Memory: [JVM] 1036M free, 1049M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3747M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Client: Application Loader 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: Upload mode selected.
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1035M free, 1049M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3747M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1025M free, 1049M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3746M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: authenticateForSession
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter DSToken = **hidden value**
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsClientStartDateTimeZoneISO = 2017-12-19T13:48:08+08:00
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsPreviousCallDurationInSecs = 0.442332601
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u 874111575@qq.com -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider 4CA5EU4K6J -f /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = 874111575@qq.com
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2017-12-19 13:48:08 CST] <main>  INFO: id = 20171219134808-355
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SharedSecret = **hidden value**
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MultipartUploadsEnabled = true
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SessionId = CPCnDBIQXjOKhVDDQRqfadZ02bRgwQ==
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: authenticateForTransportDiscovery
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsClientStartDateTimeZoneISO = 2017-12-19T13:48:09+08:00
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsPreviousCallDurationInSecs = 0.803494185
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u 874111575@qq.com -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider 4CA5EU4K6J -f /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = 874111575@qq.com
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2017-12-19 13:48:09 CST] <main>  INFO: id = 20171219134809-792
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PreferredTransports = [Aspera, Signiant, DAV]
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransportHosts.Signiant = [sgr604.apple.com:44001]
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransportHosts.DAV = [itmsdav.apple.com:443]
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransportHosts.Aspera = [vgr502.apple.com:33001, vgr503.apple.com:33001, vgr501.apple.com:33001, vgr504.apple.com:33001]
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: Examining the package at: /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: Ensuring that package has well formed metadata file...
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DEBUG: Getting case-sensitive metadata xml filename...
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: Gathering the list of valid files from the package ...
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DEBUG:   metadata.xml will be verified by Apple's web service to determine if it is a valid file.
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DEBUG:   XDSM.ipa will be verified by Apple's web service to determine if it is a valid file.
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: Finished gathering the list of valid files from the package.
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DEBUG:   Case-sensitive metadata filename is: metadata.xml
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: Performing authentication of package 1322937696.itmsp ...
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1029M free, 1051M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3734M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X: Deflated 593 bytes to 440
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: validateMetadata
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Files = [metadata.xml, XDSM.ipa]
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Metadata = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package version="software5.4" xmlns="http://apple.com/itunes/importer">
    <software_assets apple_id="1322937696"
        bundle_short_version_string="1.0"
        bundle_version="2"
        bundle_identifier="com.darren.XDSM"
        app_platform="ios">
        <asset type="bundle">
            <data_file>
                <file_name>XDSM.ipa</file_name>
                <checksum type="md5">3eb4c4b0bb0fcff3d24cc28e35773ea6</checksum>
                <size>37937294</size>
            </data_file>
        </asset>
    </software_assets>
</package>

[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataChecksum = 1ec4ae6ba192f9789b7fdb7e39e7d3e0
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataCompressed = (suppressed)
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageName = 1322937696.itmsp
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageSize = 37937887
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsClientStartDateTimeZoneISO = 2017-12-19T13:48:10+08:00
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsPreviousCallDurationInSecs = 0.695115667
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u 874111575@qq.com -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider 4CA5EU4K6J -f /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = 874111575@qq.com
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2017-12-19 13:48:10 CST] <main>  INFO: id = 20171219134810-009
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FilesToUpload = [metadata.xml, XDSM.ipa]
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter AssetsToDescribe = [{Role=source, Filename=XDSM.ipa, ShouldDescribeAsset=true, UTI=com.apple.ipa}]
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter CPUToken = 39406a48-3478-4873-9bc9-b2b525918bba/1513662491301
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Checksums = {XDSM.ipa=3eb4c4b0bb0fcff3d24cc28e35773ea6}
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FileSizes = {XDSM.ipa=37937294}
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MinimumFileSizeThresholdForCheckum = 104857600
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionFormat = binary
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionThresholds = {in-app-purchase-content={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, ccats={extensions=[pdf], size=100000000}, product-archive={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, bundle={extensions=[zip, ipa], size=100000000}, large-icon={extensions=[jpg, png, jpeg], size=100000000}}
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = true
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ProviderNameForToken = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main>  INFO: The list of files requested for upload by Apple is: [metadata.xml, XDSM.ipa].  These are the files that will be uploaded.
[2017-12-19 13:48:11 CST] <main>  INFO: Starting media analysis of assets
[2017-12-19 13:48:12 CST] <main> DEBUG: Handling asset: filename=XDSM.ipa,uti=com.apple.ipa,role=source,describe=true
[2017-12-19 13:48:12 CST] <main> DEBUG: Using container type tool name and version: iOS App Describer:1.25
[2017-12-19 13:48:12 CST] <main> DEBUG: Using path: /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp/XDSM.ipa
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> ERROR: description length:5407
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X: Asset description: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/xpg4/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin</string>
    <key>dev-tools-info</key>
    <dict>
        <key>platforms</key>
        <dict>
            <key>iPhoneOS.platform</key>
            <dict>
                <key>paths</key>
                <array>
                    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin</string>
                    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin</string>
                    <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin</string>
                    <string>/usr/local/bin</string>
                    <string>/usr/bin</string>
                    <string>/bin</string>
                    <string>/usr/sbin</string>
                    <string>/sbin</string>
                    <string>/Users/Darren/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Resources</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>search-method</key>
        <integer>2</integer>
        <key>search-method-string</key>
        <string>Launched from Xcode or App in Xcode bundle</string>
        <key>xcode-info</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <string>/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer</string>
            <key>version.plist</key>
            <dict>
                <key>BuildAliasOf</key>
                <string>IDEFrameworks</string>
                <key>BuildVersion</key>
                <string>2</string>
                <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
                <string>9.2</string>
                <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
                <string>13772</string>
                <key>ProductBuildVersion</key>
                <string>9C40b</string>
                <key>ProjectName</key>
                <string>IDEFrameworks</string>
                <key>SourceVersion</key>
                <string>13772000000000000</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>os-version</key>
    <string>10.13.2</string>
    <key>product-errors</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>code</key>
            <integer>-12000</integer>
            <key>message</key>
            <string>-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f920479c150</string>
            <key>userInfo</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSLocalizedDescription</key>
                <string>-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f920479c150</string>
                <key>NSLocalizedFailureReason</key>
                <string>-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f920479c150</string>
                <key>back-trace</key>
                <array>
                    <string>0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2ea6300b __exceptionPreprocess + 171</string>
                    <string>1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff55644c76 objc_exception_throw + 48</string>
                    <string>2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2eaf4c9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205</string>
                    <string>3   swinfo                              0x000000010d0864f8 swinfo + 5368</string>
                    <string>4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e9d93f0 ___forwarding___ + 1456</string>
                    <string>5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e9d8db8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120</string>
                    <string>6   ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d29b0f8 -[ITunesBundleDescriberContext initWithPath:infoPlist:parentContext:appType:] + 528</string>
                    <string>7   ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d29a9a1 +[ITunesBundleDescriberContext contextWithPath:infoPlist:parentContext:appType:] + 112</string>
                    <string>8   ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d286d78 -[ITunesBundleHierarchyDescriber describeBundle:context:appType:] + 310</string>
                    <string>9   ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d286759 -[ITunesBundleHierarchyDescriber describeBundlesAtPath:context:appType:] + 2374</string>
                    <string>10  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d286aff -[ITunesBundleHierarchyDescriber describeBundlesAtPath:context:appType:] + 3308</string>
                    <string>11  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d2865fa -[ITunesBundleHierarchyDescriber describeBundlesAtPath:context:appType:] + 2023</string>
                    <string>12  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d285b0e -[ITunesBundleHierarchyDescriber describeBundleHierarchyInContext:] + 895</string>
                    <string>13  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d2a72f7 -[ITunesProductMetadataDescriber describePackageAtPath:payloadPath:appType:] + 241</string>
                    <string>14  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d2a7ac5 -[ITunesProductMetadataDescriber describeProductMetadataAtPath:productutilOutput:appType:] + 1374</string>
                    <string>15  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d2a871d -[ITunesProductMetadataDescriber describeIosArchiveWithErrors:] + 590</string>
                    <string>16  ITunesSoftwareService               0x000000010d2a8aa1 -[ITunesProductMetadataDescriber describeArchiveWithErrors:] + 216</string>
                    <string>17  swinfo                              0x000000010d0874d7 swinfo + 9431</string>
                    <string>18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff56234115 start + 1</string>
                    <string>19  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>product-metadata</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>tool-path</key>
    <string>/Users/Darren/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework</string>
    <key>tool-version</key>
    <string>1.12.803</string>
</dict>
</plist>

[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DEBUG: Asset successfully described: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.software.AbstractSoftwareDescriber$1@eda25e5
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X: Deflated 5768 bytes to 1514
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main>  INFO: Asset media analysis has completed
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1040M free, 1065M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3647M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: lookupTransportDiagnostic
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsClientStartDateTimeZoneISO = 2017-12-19T13:48:13+08:00
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsPreviousCallDurationInSecs = 1.013957854
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u 874111575@qq.com -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider 4CA5EU4K6J -f /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = 874111575@qq.com
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2017-12-19 13:48:13 CST] <main>  INFO: id = 20171219134813-964
[2017-12-19 13:48:18 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-12-19 13:48:18 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter AsperaLoggingLevel = OFF
[2017-12-19 13:48:18 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SigniantLoggingLevel = OFF
[2017-12-19 13:48:18 CST] <main> DBG-X:   testing host/port: vgr503.apple.com/33001
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <aspera.util.SelectThread>  INFO: The upload of the file named /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/ec878b80-fa41-4141-8474-0a666eb8b8834083274843696377406dir/7692984f-d685-42cc-b3dc-a4bca97165003623926772759615778.txt has started.
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <aspera.util.SelectThread>  INFO:      File: /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/ec878b80-fa41-4141-8474-0a666eb8b8834083274843696377406dir/7692984f-d685-42cc-b3dc-a4bca97165003623926772759615778.txt 11/11, 100% completed
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <aspera.util.SelectThread>  INFO: The status is FINISHED for the file named /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/ec878b80-fa41-4141-8474-0a666eb8b8834083274843696377406dir/7692984f-d685-42cc-b3dc-a4bca97165003623926772759615778.txt.
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main>  INFO: The session's final state is Complete
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main>  INFO: Number of files transferred: 1 .  Names of files transferred:
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main>  INFO:     /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/ec878b80-fa41-4141-8474-0a666eb8b8834083274843696377406dir/7692984f-d685-42cc-b3dc-a4bca97165003623926772759615778.txt - Complete
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main> DEBUG: Using token file path /Users/Darren/.itmstransporter/UploadTokens/Darrenxd.local_4CA5EU4K6J_1322937696.itmsp.token
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main> DEBUG: Attempting exclusive file lock on token file
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main> DEBUG: Token exists, examining
[2017-12-19 13:48:22 CST] <main> DEBUG: Token pid: 68712, found process = false; my pid: 69410
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DEBUG: Reusing existing token: 4d74f4e2-3a37-49d8-ad7e-9d5c3bd12091/1513608085504
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DEBUG: Set token: 4d74f4e2-3a37-49d8-ad7e-9d5c3bd12091/1513608085504
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X: Memory: [JVM] 1032M free, 1065M total, 1820M max [System] (Physical) 3642M free, 16384M total (Swap) 1456M free, 3072M total
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X: Deflated 593 bytes to 440
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X: Using operation named: validateAssets
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation input parameters:
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Application = iTMSTransporter
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter BaseVersion = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter CPUToken = 4d74f4e2-3a37-49d8-ad7e-9d5c3bd12091/1513608085504
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Client = Application Loader
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ClientVersion = 3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Files = [metadata.xml, XDSM.ipa]
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ItcProviderName = 4CA5EU4K6J
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataChecksum = 1ec4ae6ba192f9789b7fdb7e39e7d3e0
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MetadataCompressed = (suppressed)
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter OSIdentifier = Mac OS X 10.13.2 (x86_64); jvm=25.71-b02; jre=1.8.0-u131-b11-iTMSTransporter-b02
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageName = 1322937696.itmsp
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter PackageSize = 37937887
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsClientStartDateTimeZoneISO = 2017-12-19T13:48:23+08:00
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter StatisticsPreviousCallDurationInSecs = 4.828341111
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Transport = Aspera
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter TransporterArguments = -m upload -u 874111575@qq.com -dsToken **hidden value** -itc_provider 4CA5EU4K6J -f /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp -checksumValidation false -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client=Application Loader -Dtransporter.client.version=3.7 (1034)
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Username = 874111575@qq.com
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Version = 1.9.6
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter iTMSTransporterMode = upload
[2017-12-19 13:48:23 CST] <main>  INFO: id = 20171219134823-726
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X: Apple's web service operation return value:
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Errors = [ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."]
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FilesToUpload = [metadata.xml, XDSM.ipa]
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter AssetsToDescribe = [{Role=source, Filename=XDSM.ipa, ShouldDescribeAsset=true, UTI=com.apple.ipa}]
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Checksums = {XDSM.ipa=3eb4c4b0bb0fcff3d24cc28e35773ea6}
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter FileSizes = {XDSM.ipa=37937294}
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter MinimumFileSizeThresholdForCheckum = 104857600
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionFormat = binary
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter SoftwareMediaDescriptionThresholds = {in-app-purchase-content={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, ccats={extensions=[pdf], size=100000000}, product-archive={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000}, bundle={extensions=[zip, ipa], size=100000000}, large-icon={extensions=[jpg, png, jpeg], size=100000000}}
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage = ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid.
 (1102)
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main>  INFO: Done performing authentication.
[2017-12-19 13:48:24 CST] <main> DBG-X: Returning 1




Package Summary:

1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
    /var/folders/6v/0rk_w63d5_36drnj7fxkd_yh0000gn/T/C9704170-47BB-4A4C-9908-A961CA73BF0A/1322937696.itmsp - Error Messages:
        description length:5407
        ERROR ITMS-90168: "The binary you uploaded was invalid."
```

Comment: What is the name of your application? Is it greater than 30 characters? If yes then try to shorten your app name.

Comment: And if you have uploaded your build using application loader then check that you have updated version of application loader or not.

Comment: May this would help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644270/xcode-9-2-upload-to-app-store-fails-with-description-length-and-invalid-toolchai/47651392

Comment: app name no more than 30 words @swapnilpatel

Comment: @Krunal I tried, did not solve

Comment: I have solved this problem because my project has a "* .bundle" file and then I get a binary error